# Brother ADS-2000 ADF Duplex Scanning not working

Tags: 12.04, scanner, brother, scanning

I'm running 12.04.

First, here are the instructions I followed to set up the printer.
[Brother Solutions Center : Brother Driver for Linux Distributions](http://support.brother.com/g/s/id/linux/en/instruction_scn1d.html?c=us_ot&lang=en&redirect=on)

And it was easy, and it works just fine with scanimage, XSane, etc... but only in simplex mode.

The scanimage help output specific to my device:

```
scanimage --help -d 'brother4:bus8;dev1'

Options specific to device `brother4:bus8;dev1':
  Mode:
    --mode Black & White|Gray[Error Diffusion]|True Gray|24bit Color|24bit Color[Fast] [24bit Color[Fast]]
        Select the scan mode
    --resolution 100|150|200|300|400|600|1200|2400|4800|9600dpi [200]
        Sets the resolution of the scanned image.
    --source Automatic Document Feeder(left aligned)|Automatic Document Feeder(left aligned,Duplex)|Automatic Document Feeder(centrally aligned)|Automatic Document Feeder(centrally aligned,Duplex) [Automatic Document Feeder(left aligned)]
        Selects the scan source (such as a document-feeder).
    --brightness -50..50% (in steps of 1) [inactive]
        Controls the brightness of the acquired image.
    --contrast -50..50% (in steps of 1) [inactive]
        Controls the contrast of the acquired image.
  Geometry:
    -l 0..215.9mm (in steps of 0.0999908) [0]
        Top-left x position of scan area.
    -t 0..355.6mm (in steps of 0.0999908) [0]
        Top-left y position of scan area.
    -x 0..215.9mm (in steps of 0.0999908) [215.88]
        Width of scan-area.
    -y 0..355.6mm (in steps of 0.0999908) [355.567]
        Height of scan-area.
```

If I run scanimage(or XSane) with source set to either of the Duplex modes, it changes nothing. I get the same single-sided scan either way. Scanimage and XSane give me no errors - it just silently delivers a single-sided scan despite my insistence that it do otherwise.

Anyone have any ideas what to look at to see where this might be failing? This thing is just perfect for me if I can just get it to work in duplex mode.

Comment: Update: sometime between when I posted this and now, it has begun to work. I have not rebooted or altered any settings related to printing, yet here I am with working duplex scanning (scanimage outputs each side to its own file).    :shrug:

Answer (score 0):

For duplex scanning you can try the GUI application `xscanimage` provided with the Ubuntu package `sane`.
You can see there the options *Scan Source: Automatic Document Feeder* and *ADF Mode: Duplex*

EPSON provides too a very good GUI for scanning ADF in duplex [iscan](http://support.epson.net/linux/en/iscan_c.html) .